# How to read *.txt files in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to load data from a file `*.txt` type to a SQL Data Base by using a Data Flow or Copy Data activity in Azure Data Factory, but I'm not being capable to do it, down below is my try

Comment: Can you share your txt file for us to have a look? The issue might have something to do with your source settings in the dataflow

Answer (score 0):

I tried with a sample **text** file and was able to get the original data in the **Source transformation** data preview.

Please check if you have selected the correct **source dataset** in your source transformation. Sometimes, when the source file is changed, it still shows old projections or incorrect projections and data previews. To reset you can change the output stream name or reconnect the source file.

Below is my source dataset connection and source settings.

**Source dataset:** text file

[image]

[image]

**Dataflow source:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Step by step instruction on how to copy only .txt file format from Source container to Target container when the source container has different formats of files using Azure Data Factory pipeline.

1. Copy the source files in the source container. I have different types of file in my source container.
   [Source container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtoo6.png)
2. Create the Target container
3. Create the pipeline and drag and drop 'Get metadata' activity to read all the source file names. Create the Dataset and the linked service pointing to the source container. Select the Dataset file format as 'Delimited Text'. In the Field List select 'Child Items' to read the file names.  [Get Metadata activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DckQS.png)
4. Drag and drop the 'Filter' activity and connect the output of the 'Get metadata' activity  to the 'Filter' activity. In the settings/Items expression builder mention `@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems`. In the settings/condition mention the expression `@contains(item().name,'.txt')` to read only the '.txt file'.
   [Filter activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUGcn.png)
5. To iterate through each of the '.txt' files use 'ForEach' activity and connect to the output of Filter activity. In the settings/Items mention the expression `@activity('Filter1').output.value` in order to read from Filter activity 'value' array.
6. Inside the 'ForEach' activity edit window drag the 'Copy data' activity. In the source setting create Dataset and linked Service pointing to the source files. Parameterize the Source DataSet to read the filename by going to the parameter tab and create a parameter. In the connection tab file path filename mention the expression `@dataset().filename`.
7. Go to the pipeline/foreach/source, in the parameter name mention the expression `@item().name`, because in the name property of the filter activity output we are getting the file name.   [foreach source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VVDZ.png)
8. In the copy data activity/sink setting, create the dataset and the linked service pointing to the target container. Open the dataset, in the Parameters tab create a parameter to read the file name and mention the parameter name in the Connections tab filenames section mention the expression `@dataset().filename`.
9. Go to the pipeline/foreach/sink - in the parameter name mention the expression `@item().name`, because we need to preserve the same file name in the target container.

Complete pipeline screenshot [complete pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsdMA.png)
Run the pipeline, only the '.txt' files will be copied to the target container.[Target container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoLxE.png)